# Need to open web page within telegram bot chat -- big picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, telegram, telegram-bot

Building my first telegram bot and it's going to be quite complex.

**Part of workflow needs to open a webview within telegram that will require user interaction, return to bot chat altering chat with data received from user.**

*Reading through the entire api, SO, github, I'm having trouble finding anything about the viewing webpages, much less if we can interact. Before I get deep into this project it would be awesome to have some starting direction.*

1. Can you create web views (like you see for "instant view" articles, google maps, etc), and if so can you get data from user to use back at the chat bot?
2. Another option is possibly using a "game". In our case, it won't be a conventional game, but maybe we could use the html5 game to render what we need, and interact with the user. I know it can pull scores, names, etc to update message, maybe we could somehow make this work?

I'm currently working through the api. This is one of my first apps, and my first telegram bot. I really appreciate any assistance on how to get started here.

This is in Rails, using https://github.com/telegram-bot-rb/telegram_bot_app as a starter. Mostly needing to know if this concept it possible, but anything more specific would be great, too. Thanks!

Comment: "Building my first telegram bot and it's going to be quite complex." this may just be me but I feel like what you want to do is a bit big for a first bot.
Also you haven't even mentioned what language you want to run the bot in or what you have done so far.

Comment: Thanks, @Hoi_A.
I'm using Rails, and have cloned https://github.com/telegram-bot-rb/telegram_bot_app to get a skeleton to start with.
For this question, didn't think it mattered, as I'm really just needing to know if what I'm trying to do is even possible -- though maybe I could get even more direction, so I'll add to post, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't create web view with the bot API and you don't need to do that. You can simply link to a web page using simple links or inline buttons and the page will open in Telegram's inline browser (Depending on user's settings).
If you include the user ID in the URL you will know who is using the webpage. e.g example.com?uid=1234

Now that you know who is using the webpage, you can use the ID to send messages or anything else in Telegram chat while user is on the webpage.
At the end you can redirect the user back to your bot URL (telegram.me/botusername).

**Update**

You can now use [Seamless Telegram Login](https://telegram.org/blog/privacy-discussions-web-bots#meet-seamless-web-bots) to link to a web page and log in the user. This feature can also be used in groups

Comment: Thanks so much, @ariaby.
So, basically, I'll have the interactive elements I need generated to the web page.
We will add the user's id to url from the bot end so we can grab it and know where to push confirmation back to.
Fun stuff!

Comment: Yes but don't forget to put some security measure so people can't just change the user_id of url

Comment: How to generate such URLs when a message is sent to the group? Is this possible, or are we talking about link being sent to a particular user and not a group here?

Comment: I updated my post, you should use Telegram seamless login for groups:
https://telegram.org/blog/privacy-discussions-web-bots#meet-seamless-web-bots

Answer (score 1):

Try the new [Telegram Web App API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps)

It can open a web page on the bottom sheet, which you can expand almost to the full screen.

You can configure the web app open button by following these steps:

- Open BotFather
- Type **/mybots**, select your bot
- Click Bot Settings > Menu Button
- Set up a menu button that opens a certain URL